# Can the complete information about a system be encoded in a Set of operators that is not tomographically complete?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, clifford-algebra

For a clifford algebra of 2N or 2N -1 operators (I hope this is the right terminology):
Operators which satisfy:
\begin{align}
\{O_i, O_j \} = \delta_{ij}
\end{align}
we know that we can represent these as matrices acting on a $2^N$ dimensional Hilbert space.
On this Hilbert space, I can write down the action of these operators as:
$$
O_i = P_{i, +} - P_{i, -}
$$

because every of those operators only has 2 eigenvalues, $+1$ and $-1$. The projection operators
$P_{i, +}$ and $P_{i, -}$ each project into the 2^(N-1) dimensional eigenspace of each of those operators. It seems to me that all the information about each of the set of operators is encoded in giving its 4N (or 2(2N-1), in case of 2N-1 operators) subspaces, along with the information wether they correspond to the eigenvalue $+1$ or $-1$.

Given the projectors, I can also write down any action of an operator like $O_i O_j$, or $O_i O_j O_k$ and so on.
Additionally, assuming a Hamiltonian that only consists of pairs $O_i O_j$, the dynamics is also complete encoded in the 4N projection operators.

However, although all the information is inside the $4N$ projection operators, it's not possible to recreate a state with these projection operators alone: With $4N$ projection operators, and assuming I have an infinite amount of copys of a given state $|\Psi \rangle$, I can only get 4N values. This is not enough to recreate the $2^N$ *2 coefficients, needed to unambigously reconstruct the state, let alone the $2^N$ absolute values of the coefficients for the basis of the system.

Why isn't that a contradiction? Are the additional, not-specified coefficients just abitrary? Appearently they don't show up in any observable.

Comment: I don't quite understand the argument for expecting the "$4N$ values" here to specify the state. What values, exactly, do you think you get from these projectors in *"I can only get 4N values"*? The eigenspaces are not one-dimensional, so to specify the image of a state under a projector you need to write down not a single number, but $2^{N-1}$ numbers - the dimension of the eigenspace. That's $4N * 2^{N-1} = N*2^{N+1}$ numbers if you do this for all projectors, which is more than enough to uniquely specify a state in $2^N$ dimensions.

Comment: @ACuriousMind the 4N values I meant were the expectation values of the projection operators. Those are the quantities that I can measure (given an infinity of copys of the same state).

Comment: Why would you expect these expectation values to fully specify the state? How would knowing these expectation values grant you knowledge of e.g. the expectation value of $[O_i,O_j]$ (which for $i < N, j = N + i$ is a spin operator, so usually something you want to be able to measure)? $\langle AB\rangle \neq \langle A\rangle\langle B\rangle$ in general!

Comment: @ACuriousMind  I would have expected these expectations values to fully specify the state, because knowing the 4N projection operators tells one anything there is to know about the state. 
Your comments made me however realize that I loose information, if I just look at the expectation values that I get from one state.

Comment: I don't know why I expected the expectation values, the values that are obtainable by the measurement, to contain all the information, if the operators do contain this information. It felt intuitive.